# Tengo un selelect dinamico en javascript, y me toma por defecto el valor de la posicion 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un `select` dinámico en **JavaScript**, que le traigo los datos por `ajax` desde la base de datos. La cuestión es que cuando me carga el `select`, siempre por defecto me toma la posición 0.

Me explico, tengo 2 `select` dinámicos, el segundo depende de lo que seleccione en el primero, por eso el segundo siempre me aparece cargado porque en el primero esta tomando el valor de la posición 0...

Yo lo que quiero es que al cargar la pagina **HTML**, el `select` no tome ningún valor, hasta cuando yo lo seleccione.... Mando el **HTML** y después el **JS**...

```js
//obtengo las secciones
function DesplegarSecc() {
    $("#slcSecciones").empty();
    var dir = "CargoSeccion";
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir,
        success: function(seccion) {

            var secc = seccion;
            console.log(secc);
            for (var i = 0; i < secc.length; i++) {
                $("#slcSecciones").append("<option value=" + secc[i] + ">" + secc[i] + "</option>");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}

// este es el segundo select dinamico que depende del primero


//obtengo las categorias
function DesplegarCatXSecc(NombreSeccion) {
    $("#slcCategorias").empty();
    var dir = "CargoCategoria";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion,
        success: function(categorias) {
            var cat = categorias;
            for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
                // if(idSeccion == cat[i].idSeccion)
                $("#slcCategorias").append("<option value=" + cat[i] + " >" + cat[i] + "</option>")
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

```html
     <div>
                <b>Secci&oacute;n:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcSecciones">
                    <option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <div>
                <b>Categor&iacute;a:</b> &nbsp;
                <select id="slcCategorias">
                        <option selected disabled>Seleccione una opci&oacute;n...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Un select siempre toma un valor. Lo único que puedes es cargar un valor por defecto tu tipo "Seleccione una opción"

Comment: Si, es que hago eso, ahora arregle el codigo q lo habia publicado mal
Me toma el de la posicion 0, osea, cuando me carga el select dinamico, ya queda por defecto el de la posicion 0..

Comment: Si no le indicas ninguno como seleccionado siempre te va a coger el primero.

Comment: como se resuelve eso?

Comment: Tienes que poner en el que necesites `<option selected ... />`

Comment: podrias ser mas especifico? Si ves mi codigo html ya tengo un option selected, pero sigue tomandome el valor 0

Comment: ¿A que llamas valor cero?

Comment: perdon me exprese mal, la posicion 0, ya por defecto los select que tengo cargados, me toman el valor de la posicion 0, por eso, mi segundo select, al depender del valor tomado en el primero, siempre me aparece cargado...

Comment: No acabo de entenderte, puedes poner un ejemplo de como se sale y otro de como quieres que te salga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es normal que te esté tomando el valor del primer `option` que agregas al `select`, esto pasa porque antes de iterar los resultados y llenar el `select` lo estas limpiando completamente usando el método `.empty()` y luego lo vuelves a llenar quedando como primer `option` el primer elemento iterado y de forma predeterminada como valor seleccionado.

Lo que tienes que hacer no es vaciar los `select` antes de llenarlos si no "reiniciarlos" a la estructura que has indicado en el **HTML**.

```
function DesplegarSecc() {
    $("#slcSecciones").html('<option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>');
    var dir = "CargoSeccion";
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir,
        success: function(seccion) {

            var secc = seccion;
            console.log(secc);
            for (var i = 0; i < secc.length; i++) {
                $("#slcSecciones").append("<option value=" + secc[i] + ">" + secc[i] + "</option>");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}

function DesplegarCatXSecc(NombreSeccion) {
    $("#slcCategorias").html('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opci&oacute;n...</option>');
    var dir = "CargoCategoria";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion,
        success: function(categorias) {
            var cat = categorias;
            for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
                // if(idSeccion == cat[i].idSeccion)
                $("#slcCategorias").append("<option value=" + cat[i] + " >" + cat[i] + "</option>")
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

O bien, también podrías vaciarlos tal cual como lo haces actualmente pero antes de iniciar el ciclo `for` añadir manualmente los dos `option` definidos en el **HTML**.

```
function DesplegarSecc() {
    $("#slcSecciones").empty();
    var dir = "CargoSeccion";
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir,
        success: function(seccion) {

            var secc = seccion;
            console.log(secc);
            $("#slcSecciones").append("<option selected disabled>Seleccione...</option>");
            for (var i = 0; i < secc.length; i++) {
                $("#slcSecciones").append("<option value=" + secc[i] + ">" + secc[i] + "</option>");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}

function DesplegarCatXSecc(NombreSeccion) {
    $("#slcCategorias").empty();
    var dir = "CargoCategoria";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion,
        success: function(categorias) {
            var cat = categorias;
            $("#slcCategorias").append("<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opci&oacute;n...</option>");
            for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
                // if(idSeccion == cat[i].idSeccion)
                $("#slcCategorias").append("<option value=" + cat[i] + " >" + cat[i] + "</option>")
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, fue la solucion a mi problema!! Crack